# How to resolve this error for invalid credential in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

Please help me to rectify this error.

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}}
```

Comment: Your not logging in correctly please edit your question and include the code you are using to authenticate and request data

Comment: Check your credentials for API again, app secret etc